# Am I calling my DATABASE_URL correctly with Axios? (CORS error with Heroku Postgres..)

Tags: heroku, cors, postgres

I am trying to deploy an app using a combination of NodeJS, Heroku, and the Postgres add-on database. Everything works fine when I deploy locally. When I try to deploy off of Heroku, however, I get the following CORS error:

*"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'postgres://{USERNAME}:{PASSWORD}@{HOST}:5432/:{DATABASE}/user' from origin 'https://{APP-NAME}.herokuapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy."*

I've spent the past day or so trying to figure out this error. There are a number of solutions on StackOverflow, and I've gone through most of them, as well as Heroku's documentation, to try out and test their solutions. This includes:

1. [Setting the appropriate DATABASE_URL environment variable in Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql), and getting rid of any references to the local .env variables within production
2. Ensuring that [SSL is being enforced by the client](https://help.heroku.com/3DELT3RK/why-can-t-my-third-party-utility-connect-to-heroku-postgres-with-ssl) when connecting to the database
3. [Ensuring that CORS is properly set up on production.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53875548/cors-problems-on-heroku) It should be noted that I had already fixed all my CORS issues on my localhost connection and had no issues, and believe that I've probably addressed them in prodution as well. Therefore, I'm not sure it's the main problem here...?

Addressing these issues did not seem to fix the problem. I suspect the issue has to do with the way I am calling my database URL using Axios? As one can see from the above, the DATABASE_URL which I am getting directly from Heroku is in the format "postgres://USERNAME/PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/DATABASE". However, it looks odd when I call it using, say, Axios?

When I try to make use 3rd party software like Postman or Postbird to make an HTTP test call, it fails, but I think that's due to the SSL requirement. Therefore, I can't tell what is the proper way to make calls using the DATABASE_URL. This is what my Axios call looks like (with process.env.DATABASE_URL obviously referring to the URL):

```
const fetchUsers = async () => {
    const response = await axios
      .get(process.env.DATABASE_URL+ "/users")
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));

    if (response) {
      const offers = response.data;  

      console.log("Users: ", users);
      setUsers(users);
    }
  };
```

If the route was just localhost, the URL look like: localhost:3000//users. But for such a long and complex connection string, does the above look like the right way to be *getting* using the DATABASE_URL and Axios?

Sorry for the long question and thanks in advance...

Comment: Step 3 of your setup creates a middleware service based on Express; this is where CORS headers are set to allow the call from the client. You're calling DB directly via `postgres://`, this won't work as Heroku PG does not handle CORS out of the box. If you can use [Datalips](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dataclips) for your use case, it supports CORS.